# Hadoop MapReduce Sorting levels

Tags: sorting, mapreduce, workflow, shuffle

How many levels of sorting happens in a map reduce program? Is the sorting part of shuffling? I am totally confused with this?

Can you please help with the flow diagram for the MR workflow including all the steps? Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good article with a diagram is [A Beginners Guide to Hadoop](http://blog.matthewrathbone.com/2013/04/17/what-is-hadoop.html) and [Blog on Clouder](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/03/the-truth-about-mapreduce-performance-on-ssds/)

Sort and Merge use SortComparator and grouping uses GroupingComparator.

Secondary sort is the best example to understand the intricacies of sorting in hadoop.

**UPDATE:**

On a very high level, hadoop MR can be seen as distributed Sort Merge. When Mapper is working it produces sorted spills for each Reducer (using SortComparator), if Mapper had produced a couple of spills for each Reducer, than on the Mapper side it could Sort Merge them into large spill using SortComparator. Before all Mappers finish, Reducers are launched and start pulling their spills from each Mapper and sort merge them using SortComparator. When all Mappers have finished and spills on each reducer side are under a freehold, than data is sorted and Reducers will use GroupComparator to identify which sorted Key/Value pairs are covered by the Iterator values of the reduce call.

Comment: So who does the sorting and grouping(group the results of all the mappers by key)? another question is,  Is the output of the resducers are always sorted by key? Thanks.